# String Matching KMP

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write lps function for KMP algorithm. But, I am getting this error.

```
if pattern[i] == pattern[j]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my code

```py
def get_lps(pattern):

    pattern = list(pattern)
    lps = [0 for i in range(len(pattern))]
    i = 1
    j = 0
    while i!= len(pattern) :
        if pattern[i] == pattern[j]:
            lps[i] = j + 1
            i += 1
            j += 1

        else :
            if j!= 0:
                j = pattern[j-1]
            else:
                lps[i] = 0
                i += 1

    return lps
print(get_lps("abcabcaa"))
```

Comment: you have a line `j = pattern[j-1]`, pattern is a string, and so `pattern[j-1]` (a single char string)

Comment: Oh silly mistake, Cheers bro.

Answer (score 0):

j = pattern[j-1] should be replaced by j = lps[j-1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31477963)